# How can I tell I have uncommited queries?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Developer requires clicking the Commit button to validate my queries so far. My issue is that I've been used to 5 years of auto-commit (bad, I know) and I have a hard time remembering to Commit and then 1) wonder why data doesn't change, 2) end up locking tables because of unfinished transaction.

Is there any telltale sign that something uncommited remains **in the UI**?

I would prefer to focus on a UI feedback, if there is any.

Comment: I work with PLSQL developer which has a greyed out commit button when there are no outstanding changes and an active one when there are. SQL developer's commit button seems to be always on.

Comment: @Rene: I wish I could choose my tools but in this case I can't... Good to know though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select s.sid
      ,s.serial#
      ,s.username
      ,s.machine
      ,s.status
      ,s.lockwait
      ,t.used_ublk
      ,t.used_urec
      ,t.start_time
from v$transaction t
inner join v$session s on t.addr = s.taddr;
```

or simply this:

```
SELECT * FROM V$TRANSACTION WHERE STATUS='ACTIVE';
```

And if you have the session id with you then you may try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    v$session x
WHERE   x.AUDSID = userenv('yoursessionid')
    AND x.TADDR IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You can check [Logminer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/logminer.htm#SUTIL019) too

Comment: Shouldn't that be `userenv('SID')` to get the current session id?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- Yes Sir it can be. But I made it generic so that if the OP wants to check for other sessions then also it will work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to see what your session still keeps active transaction is to use dbms_transaction Oracle package:

```
SQL> select dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id from dual;

LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


SQL> update t set x = x;

3 rows updated.

SQL> select dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id from dual;

LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9.9.460109
```